# Why am I getting the error "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported. "

Tags: javascript

I have looked at the other questions, but still can't come up with an answer.

When a user clicks the "Save Project" button, this function is fired:

```
function common_save_project()
{
  var image = common_screenshot();
}
```

That calls common_screenshot()

```
function common_screenshot()
{
  var canvas = document.getElementById("save_image_canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  if (typeof(moulding_canvas) === "undefined")
  {
    canvas.height = parseInt($("#matte_canvas").height());
    canvas.width = parseInt($("#matte_canvas").width());
  }
  else
  {
    canvas.height = parseInt($("#moulding_canvas").height());
    canvas.width = parseInt($("#moulding_canvas").width());
  }
  canvas.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";

  var moulding_top = 0;
  var moulding_left = 0;
  if (document.getElementById("moulding_canvas"))
  {
    moulding_top = -1 * parseInt(document.getElementById("moulding_canvas").style.top);
    moulding_left = -1 * parseInt(document.getElementById("moulding_canvas").style.left);
  }

  var mattes_html = document.getElementById("mattes").innerHTML;
  mattes_html = mattes_html.replace(/<\/?script\b.*?>/g, "");
  mattes_html = mattes_html.replace(/ on\w+=".*?"/g, "");
  console.log(mattes_html);
  rasterizeHTML.drawHTML(mattes_html).then(function (renderResult) 
  {
    ctx.drawImage(renderResult.image, moulding_left, moulding_top);
  });

  ctx.drawImage(matte_canvas, moulding_left, moulding_top);
  if (typeof(moulding_canvas) !== "undefined")
  {
    ctx.drawImage(moulding_canvas, 0, 0);
  }
  //var image = new Image();
    //image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
  //return image;
}
```

Then a new canvas is generated and next to it is a test button. When that is clicked:

```
function common_test()
{
  var canvas = document.getElementById("save_image_canvas");
  var image = new Image();
  image.setAttribute('crossOrigin','anonymous');
    image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
  $.ajax
  (
    {
      type: "POST",
      processData: false,
      url:  SITE_URL + "/system/xml/import/" + app_type + "/" + session_id + "/?prjid=" + project_id,
      data: "xml=" + common_order_xml + "&prodid=" + product_id + "&file=" + image.src
    }
  ).done(function( msg ) 
  {
      console.log("Project saved. " + msg);
  });
}
```

However when I click that button, I get the error:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.
```

EDIT: It appears that the error is happening when I have the following:

```
rasterizeHTML.drawHTML(mattes_html).then(function (renderResult) 
{
  ctx.drawImage(renderResult.image, moulding_left, moulding_top);
});
```

Is there another solution I can use to turn html markup into an image that I can then use in `canvas.toURL`

Answer (score 1):

You are loading files from the local file system, instead of using a localhost request.

Run your application through a localhost file server, and make sure to load files in your app only through http:// and not from the local system. (i.e. c:/ or file:// or /usr)

Comment: I not using localhost. I am using an actual domain.

Comment: Then you're having crossdomain issues.
for security reasons canvas will disallow assets loaded from a different domain.

Comment: All my images are coming from the same domain. I am not requesting anything from a different domain.

Comment: Read up on tainted canvases: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image

Comment: I did... I added that stuff to my .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

Just use `crossOrigin` Attribute

```
var image= new Image();
image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
image.src = url;
```

Comment: It doesn't work because, in my case, the server is not sending the CORS headers. Without the `crossOrigin` attribute I can load the images but using it I can't

Comment: @IonelLupu this is the same issue that I currently have, I can load the images to canvas, but i cannot generate toBaseURL(). Have you found any solution to this? It would be really helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't a nice solution to this. My solution is to have a backend service that will download the image and serve it to the frontend. This way you will go around the error. I know it's not nice but it works.